# What is this carefree succulent flowering potted plant?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials, succulents

Anyone know what plant this is?

It was planted in a large pot a long time ago by a friend. The dirt in the pot has not been changed for years! It blooms around the summer time and stays till mid winter. It is located in New York. It also has a poke berry vine 
growing on the side of it.

*click the images for full size*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that the plant in question is in the picture to the left. The picture to the right appears to be the poke berry vine or some such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [*Sedum spectabile*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylotelephium_spectabile), aka *Hylotelephium spectabile*. The common name is stonecrop. It is a succulent perennial hardy in all temperate regions, and has been introduced to many of these areas as an ornamental. The flowers attract lots of pollinators, as well as a variety of butterflies. The plant in your picture has finished flowering, and is developing seedheads. Here's a comparison pic:

[image]

Comment: They're good at attracting honeybees where I'm from.

Comment: So I'm guessing that the color difference is because the flower is dead?

Comment: @LoneWolf Yes, your plant has finished flowering and is going to seed. Also, different varieties from this species can have differently colored flowers.

Comment: How do I know it has seeded and how can I harvest it?

Comment: @LoneWolf When the stalk is completely dry, the seeds are ready. You may find the following useful: http://www.garden.org/searchqa/index.php?q=show&id=14865&ps=84&keyword=seed&adv=0. For a full answer, you can ask this as a new question. ;)